# How to derive the maximum difference of two variable integers of different signs with respect to a constant?

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, functions

I am trying to derive a function that specifies the delta in the maximum of the absolute summation an integer A and B or C whereby the following constraints apply:

- A can be positive or negative but is a constant
- B can only be positive (B >= 0)
- C can only be negative (C <= 0)

Again I am trying to calculate the resultant value X which should stipulate the delta in the maximum value of B or C with respect to A, I have outlined a number of examples below which show what I am trying to achieve, whereby B1 and C1 represent the initial values and B2 and C2 represent the target/next values of B and C respectively with the resulting X being a function of the change therin.

1) B and C are removed/changed to zero

```
A = 100 

B1 = 100
C1 = -100 

B2 = 0
C2 = 0

X = -100
```

2) B partially changed

```
A = -100 

B1 = 100
C1 = -100 

B2 = 50
C2 = 0

X = -50
```

3) B increased, C removed

```
A = 100 

B1 = 100
C1 = -100 

B2 = 200
C2 = 0

X = 100
```

4) C increased does nothing because A + B1 >= ((A + C2) - (A + C1))

```
A = 100 

B1 = 100
C1 = -100 

B2 = 100
C2 = -200

X = 0
```

5) Nothing changes

```
A = -100 

B1 = 0
C1 = 0 

B2 = 0
C2 = 0

X = 0
```

6) C2 is increased and is greater than A

```
A = -100 

B1 = 0
C1 = 0 

B2 = 0
C2 = -300

X = 300
```

7) B increases and is greater than A and sign(B2) != sign(A)

```
A = -100 

B1 = 0
C1 = 0 

B2 = 300
C2 = 0

X = 200
```

8) A is zero B increases

```
A = 0 

B1 = 0
C1 = 0 

B2 = 100
C2 = 0

X = 100
```

9) A is zero C increases X proportional to increase

```
A = 0 

B1 = 0
C1 = 0 

B2 = 0
C2 = -100

X = 100
```

10) A is zero both C and B equally increased:

```
A = 0 

B1 = 0
C1 = 0 

B2 = 100
C2 = -100

X = 100
```

(please let me know if you require any additional examples)

I have tried numerous methods but all have edge cases that invalidate them (implemented in python):

1) The following fails when B2 > A:

```
x=(abs(max([-A+C2, A+B2], key=abs))-abs(A)) - (abs(max([-A+C1, A+B1], key=abs))-abs(A))
```

2) The following fails when B1, B2, C1, C2 are all 0 and returns A:

```
abs(max([-A+C2, A+B2], key=abs)) + abs(max([-A+C1, A+C2], key=abs)) - abs(A)
```

Could someone please advise me on how to succinctly implement this functionality/logic, thanks.

If there is anything that I might have left out, please let me know.